# How to implement transactions with node promises

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, transactions, promise

I'm developing an application with `node`,`mysql` and `angular4`. There , I have set of functions that related to a single task. all these are asynchronous function that works with promises that look like this

```
setAprroveTrue(curentHOD, user, group, message, approvemail, approved_byHR = 0) { //HR or super admin can override anyones leave. default it is set as not by and hr.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Leaves.setHodMessage(group, message, curentHOD).then((messageArr) => {
                q = "update leave_taken_superior_map set lstm_col_status= ? ,ltsm_all_approved = 1,ltsm_overide_by_hr = ?,ltsm_message = ? where ltsm_group_id = ?;update leave_taken set alt_leave_approved = 1 where alt_group_by = ?";
                params = [config.key_word_approved_leave, approved_byHR, messageArr, group, group];
                sqlq.executeQuery(q, params).then((data) => {
                    if (approvemail === true) {
                        emails.sendEmail('pavithrarox1@gmail.com', 'pavithra@gmail.lk', 'Good news! Your leave request has been approved', emails.getLeaveApprovedEmail(group))
                    } else {
                        emails.sendEmail('pavithrarox1@gmail.com', 'pavithra@gmail.lk', 'Bad news! Your leave request has been rejected', emails.getLeaveDissapprovedEmail(group))
                    }
                    //no need to wait for email to send.it will work as a background procass
                    resolve(data)
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject(err)
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err)
            })
        })
    }
```

How can I implement transactions in this function?
So, if `setHodMessage` function executed successfully and if something goes wrong with `executeQuery` function. How do i roll back everything?

Comment: Looks like you already implemented it. If something's wrong with the current implementation please state it explicitly in the question.

Comment: no i havent implemented transactions here. in setHodMessage method it updates the table of the database with some data and in executeQuery function also do the same thing. but if executeQuery function does not get executed for some reason there is no point of executing setHodMessage  method. so i want to rollback what happened there.

Comment: Now I'm confused: this question is about how to [implement transactions in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) or about nodejs ?

Comment: how to implement transaction in mysql when we use nodejs with promises

Comment: how to implement transaction in mysql doesn't have anything to do with the language you're using to call the DB. The transaction is implemented in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the issue here. the reason i could not get transactions to work on my application is because i have used `mysql.createPool` instead of `mysql.createConnection`. there is no option to implement transactions in createPool

Answer (score 0):

You can work on the reject case and apply the logic likewise.

SO every promise has  resolve and reject and a catch block

```
promise.then(
      resolved=>{},
      reject=>{}
).catch(error=>{});
```

So in your case .

```
setAprroveTrue(curentHOD, user, group, message, approvemail, approved_byHR = 0) { //HR or super admin can override anyones leave. default it is set as not by and hr.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Leaves.setHodMessage(group, message, curentHOD).then((messageArr) => {
                q = "update leave_taken_superior_map set lstm_col_status= ? ,ltsm_all_approved = 1,ltsm_overide_by_hr = ?,ltsm_message = ? where ltsm_group_id = ?;update leave_taken set alt_leave_approved = 1 where alt_group_by = ?";
                params = [config.key_word_approved_leave, approved_byHR, messageArr, group, group];
                sqlq.executeQuery(q, params).then((data) => {
                    if (approvemail === true) {
                        emails.sendEmail('pavithrarox1@gmail.com', 'pavithra@gmail.lk', 'Good news! Your leave request has been approved', emails.getLeaveApprovedEmail(group))
                    } else {
                        emails.sendEmail('pavithrarox1@gmail.com', 'pavithra@gmail.lk', 'Bad news! Your leave request has been rejected', emails.getLeaveDissapprovedEmail(group))
                    }
                    //no need to wait for email to send.it will work as a background procass
                    resolve(data)
                },()=>{  
                        //do your rollback stuff here
                      }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject(err)
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err)
            })
        })
    }
```

Lemme know if you want any help.